# How would a aquatic race make ships

Tags: merfolk, shipbuilding

How would an aquatic race make ships for underwater travel, how would they deal with the pressure of the deep ocean or build warships, make transports and the like. Curiosity for a campaign set in an alternate ww2 fantasy world.

Comment: How aquatic?  Do these people live like fish or dolphins?

Comment: similar:  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/189520/what-kind-of-ships-would-an-amphibious-species-build

Comment: What is the purpose of the ships, if it is fast travel is surface ships ok?

Comment: you mean submarine right? since you say underwater travel, though even modern submarine has their limit range to withstand under deep water pressure.

Comment: also are the aquatic race breathing using gills or lungs? i think that can also impact the transportations too, since in human case they need to consider the balance of breathable oxygen inside it and not flooded, which maybe not the case for gill type, so the submarine/ship design maybe entirely different in principle to withstand the water pressure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What kind of ships would an amphibious species build?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/189520/what-kind-of-ships-would-an-amphibious-species-build)

Answer (score 0):

The evolution of water breather transportation would probably mimic that of air breathers.  At first, fast, strong and high endurance sea life would be ridden directly without tackle or saddle.  Later, those same creatures would be domesticated and bred to be faster, stronger and longer lasting.  The equipment of riding would then evolve becoming saddles for individuals and carriages for group transport.
Military aquatic riders would probably adapt to using slave power instead of sea animals because slaves are easier to come by in combat conditions.  Winners remains slave masters while the losers become new slaves.

Beyond that point, the parallels evolution would probably end because the water breathers lack anything comparable to coal to fuel artificial power sources for their vehicles.